# Flexslider Does Not Work in Firefox or Safari

Tags: jquery, flexslider

Hi I'm trying to use Flexslider for my Bigcommerce site, which works in Chrome, but not in Safari or Firefox 27.0.1. It just shows all the images on top of each other, no sliding.

I tried this solution:

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/958

but doesn't work.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: you might consider switching to jquery cycle2: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/
...pretty sure it does everything flexslider can do

Comment: This is possibly the most vague question I've seen on here. No examples, screenshots, code, or even console errors. Please provide some more detail so we can help! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am also facing the same problem. Checked console on FireFox and error is this one:

ReferenceError: onTouchStart is not defined
   el.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);

jquery....ider.js (linha 398, col 12)

So... I don't know what to do! :(

EDIT:

I had this issue solved by downloading this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miketaylr/FlexSlider/8af7e0d02d332da4ca8e9dc094f6dd4aa3933d6d/jquery.flexslider.js

Hope this helps future visitors too!

Comment: This solved it for me too. I'm on Firefox on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1-you must add this css  :

> .rtl.widget-carousel{
> direction: ltr; }

2-add this code in js:

> ```
> $('.flexslider').flexslider({
>     animation: "slide",
>     rtl: false,
>     slideshow: true,
> });
> ```